# Evaluate the integral $\int (4x^7- 12 \cos x) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am evaluating this integral $$\int (4x^7- 12 \cos x) \,dx$$ but I am not sure where to start. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Hint: use the fact that $\int f(x)-g(x)dx = \int f(x)dx - \int g(x)dx$ and make use of the integration formulas $\int x^{n}dx = x^{n+1}/(n+1) + C$ and $\int \cos x dx = \sin x + C$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The integral of a sum or difference of functions is equal to the sum or difference of the integrals of each function:  In short, $$\int \Big(a\cdot f(x) \pm b\cdot g(x)\Big)\,dx \;\;= \;\;a\int f(x)\,dx \;\;\pm \;\;b\int g(x)\,dx$$

In your case:

$$\begin{align} \int\left (4x^7 - 12 \cos(x)\right)\,dx &= 4\int x^7\,dx - 12 \int \cos(x)\,dx\\
&= \left(4\cdot \dfrac {x^8}{8} \right) - \left(12\cdot \sin x\right) + C\\
&= \frac 12 x^8 - 12 \sin x + C
\end{align}$$